# Create Bash Script From CURL Value

Tags: bash, shell, logic

i wanna ask, just create simple shell script from curl with this condition. but when the curl status is true the else condition is never success, what is my misatake? any suggestion will be appreciate. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
code=$(curl -sX GET "http://10.243.215.143:8088/healthcheck")
if [[ $code != true ]];
then
  echo "restart service"
else
  echo "service is up"
fi
```

[curl result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQRXQ.png)

my expectation is where the curl status all **true** the script running the else condition.

Comment: From the image you posted the `curl` command is apparently outputting `json` so pipe it's output to `jq` to print the `isHealthy` value and then test that. If you need more help then ask a new question but don't post images, just text.

Comment: You should always try to avoid writing negative logic like `if [[ $code != true ]]`  since positive logic is easier to understand and if you write negative logic you can end up with double negatives, e.g. try to state the condition under which "service is up" is printed and it's "it is NOT true that $code is NOT equal to true" which is a double negative. If you just flip the logic to `if [[ "$code" == "true" ]]; then echo "service is up"; else echo "restart service"; fi` it's immediately a bit clearer and has no double negative.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your reply and your suggestion it's little bit clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using command substitution, the result can't be boolean.
When you use the format

```
VARNAME=$(command)
```

$VARNAME will contain the output of command, that is normally a string.
In addition you are receiving output in json format, so you'll have to extract a specific field from the json, I guess "isHealthy".
You should review your script as follow

```
#!/bin/bash
code=$(curl -sX GET "http://10.243.215.143:8088/healthcheck" | jq ".isHealthy")

if [[ "$code" != "true" ]];
then
  echo "restart service"
else
  echo "service is up"
fi
```

On the other hand, if you want to check curl return code just call the curl command, then you'll have curl return code in the special **$?** bash variable.

Comment: Hi Francesco, thanks for your suggestion i tried to my code and it's works. Thanks in advice

Comment: the reason command not working before i'm not used jq plugins yet.